# How can I find the function $f(n)$

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the function $f(n)$ if,
 $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-2^{2 n - 1} + 2^{8 n - 3} - 3}{-2^{2 f(n) - 1} + 2^{2 f(n) + 3} - 3} = 1$$

Comment: Are you sure about the expression ?

Comment: I think it means $n\rightarrow-\infty$.

Comment: For example: you can try $k=3$, $k=4$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yes of course...

Comment: Maybe I wrote wrong.Now I'm fixing.

Comment: Sorry..I  fixed. Now limit is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After discarging neglectible terms, the numerator is asymptotic to $2^{8n-3}$, while the denominator is asymptotic to $2^{2f(n)}(-2^{-1}+2^3)$.

By identification of the base $2$ logarithms,

$$8n-3=2f(n)+\log_2\frac{15}2.$$

---

It is improper to speak of *the* sequence, as any sequence asymptotic to this $f(n)$ can do.